# Atom editor - Snippets error ".atom\snippets.cson: reserved word "class" can't be assigned"

Tags: markdown, atom-editor

I'm getting following error while creating atom snippet. How to escape reserved words in atom snippets.

It is a markdown snippet.

`'.source.gfm':
'hugo-shortcode-best-tip.md':
    'prefix': '_hsbt'
    'body': """{{< best-practice class="$3" >}}"""`

Error

`text
.atom\snippets.cson: reserved word "class" can't be assigned`

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this copying and pasting your snippet into my own

Comment: My apologies, I should have deleted the question. it was due to  missing `"""`